# AWS hosted zone is passing DNS check but not resolving

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-elb

Am trying to link my godaddy domain to AWS app linked to AWS loadbalancer, I have set my godaddy nameserver settings to AWS

and on AWS I have created `A` and `CNAME` records pointing to the ELB.

testing the sites on https://dnschecker.org/ seems to pass, but the website is not loading, when I open the loadbalancer directly it loads okey, what could be the issue ?

[image]

Comment: If you choose to obfuscate your domain name and don't share any debugging information, we really can't help you.